# How do I delete the same thing in an array of cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a column of 100+ cells that all contain a bullet point in them.

Am I able to run a macro or some function that will delete all bullet points and just leave the text remaining in the cell?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one-liner:

```
Sub BulletKiller()
    Cells.Replace what:=Chr(149), replacement:=""
End Sub
```

assumes your bullets are ASCII 0149.  All cells in the active worksheet will be processed.  All bullets will be removed, even bullets in the middle of text or at the end of text.

Comment: Really nice solution.